# Transfer function of a basic RC circuit

Tags: transfer-function

I'm having a hard time getting my head around finding the transfer function.

I have a circuit that looks like this:

```
 o----------R-------C-----------o
                         |   
                         |
                         C
                         |
                         |
 o------------------------------o
```

The solutions in my book say the answer is $$\frac{(RC)^{-1}}{s + 2(RC)^{-1}}$$ where s = jω. How did they get this?

Help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the risk of doing your homework for you,

Start with the voltage divider rule

$$\frac{V_o}{V_i}=\frac{Z_C}{R+Z_C+Z_C}$$

where \$Z_C\$ is the impedance associated with a capacitor with value *C*.

Now substitute

$$\frac{V_o}{V_i}=\frac{1/sC}{R+2/sC}$$

Now multiply by \$\frac{sC}{sC}\$

$$\frac{V_o}{V_i}=\frac{1}{sRC+2}$$

Now divide both the numerator and denominator by \$RC\$ to isolate \$s\$.

$$\frac{V_o}{V_i}=\frac{(RC)^{-1}}{s+2(RC)^{-1}}$$

Comment: This isn't homework, it was from an assignment which we got the solutions to after the due date, I just wanted to learn it for exams. I really appreciate your help, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

use the Laplace/frequency analysis

\begin{gather}
    Z_{R} = R \\ 
    Z_{C} = \frac{1}{sC} \\
\end{gather}

So than you use the normal circuit law you know. This circuit is a Voltage divider(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider) . So:

\begin{gather}
    V_{out} =  V_{in}\frac{Z_{C}}{Z_{C}+Z_{C}+Z_{R}} \\ 
    V_{out} =  V_{in}\frac{Z_{C}}{2Z_{C}+Z_{R}} \\ 
    V_{out} =  V_{in}\frac{\frac{1}{sC}}{2\frac{1}{sC}+R } \\ 
    V_{out} =  V_{in}\frac{1}{2+sCR } \\ 
    V_{out} =  V_{in}\frac{\frac{1}{RC}}{2\frac{1}{RC}+s } \\ 
    \frac{V_{out}}{V_{in}} =  \frac{\frac{1}{RC}}{2\frac{1}{RC}+s } \\ 
\end{gather}

Regards MathieuL.